# QGIS3.3 - Batch processing for getting $areas on multiple layers - errors

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, batch

Hej! I try to calculate the area for several layers. I tried to use the batch processing tool (see img) through the Graphic Model processing tool but it gives me errors. Since I used the function `$area` I don't know if I should give him more inputs (such as the CSR for instance, or one field in my attribute table like the object ID to help him to calculate the area from something...)Can you help?[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide more details on your model.

Comment: I edit my post, however I am really unsure about my model